# Why is instead of the Vue component some JS comment added to the DOM?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am working with BootstrapVue and am trying to dynamically create components after the site is rendered (I want to use asynchronous data for the generation process later) with Vue and add them to the DOM.

(I am simulating the asynchrony in the demo by creating the components with a 1 second delay after the page is loaded).

This is what happens:
Vue is creating the components and then they should be mounted to the DOM. But sadly they don't show up. Instead this comment: `<!--function(e,n,r,i){return Pt(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}-->` is added to them DOM (at the correct position though) in place of the actual HTML code of the component.

This is the jsfiddle with example code that demonstrates the problem: **https://jsfiddle.net/0stdxorj/1**

Thank you for your help :).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap Vue CSS -->
    <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../vrc/vrc.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Using: https://bootstrap-vue.org/ -->
    <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver"></script>
    <!-- Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Portal Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/portal-vue@latest/dist/portal-vue.umd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <!-- VCalendar JS -->
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/v-calendar'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- Application root element -->
    <b-container fluid="xl">

        <b-row align-h="center" align-v="start" id="card-container">
            <!-- Card Inline Template -->
            <card inline-template id="card-template">
                <b-card
                        v-bind:title=card.title
                        img-src="https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=25"
                        img-alt="Image"
                        img-top
                        style="max-width: 370px; margin: 5px"
                        class="no-select"
                >
                    <b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-' + card.id">Button</b-button>
                    <b-collapse v-bind:id="'collapse-' + card.id" class="mt-2">
                        <v-calendar
                                is-expanded
                                :min-date='new Date()'
                        >
                        </v-calendar>
                    </b-collapse>
                </b-card>
            </card>
        </b-row>

    </b-container>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})

const cardComponentConstructor = Vue.extend({
    props: {
        card: {
            required: true,
            default: {id: 0, title: 'Default.'}
        }
    },
    template: '#card-template',
    mounted() {
        alert("mounted " + this.card.id + " " + this.card.title)
    },
    created() {
        //alert("created " + this.card.id + " " + this.card.title)
    }
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        createCard({propsData: {card: {id: 0, title: '0'}}})
        createCard({propsData: {card: {id: 1, title: '1'}}})
    }, 1000);
});

function createCard(props) {
    let componentInstance = new cardComponentConstructor(props)
    componentInstance.$mount()
    document.getElementById("card-container").appendChild(componentInstance.$el)
}
```

Comment: This seems like a strange way to go about it. Why the `inline-template`? Why the manual child creation? Could you explain why you aren't just using a `v-if` to show the child?

Comment: I use `inline-template` because I haven't fully figured out how to make a template from a file yet. I could use `v-if` to show the child in the future but my priority was fixing the asynchronous card generation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going at it in another way. Vue re-renders `v-for` tags when using a `key` attribute (`:key="card.id"`). So I don't try to manually create the components anymore but make use of this feature and modify the `cards` data instead, which in turn then makes Vue re-render the deleted/modified/added cards:

Updated jsfiddle with my solution **https://jsfiddle.net/t7k49a2n/**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap Vue CSS -->
    <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../vrc/vrc.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Using: https://bootstrap-vue.org/ -->
    <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver"></script>
    <!-- Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Portal Vue JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/portal-vue@latest/dist/portal-vue.umd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <!-- VCalendar JS -->
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/v-calendar'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- Application root element -->
    <b-container fluid="xl">

        <b-row align-h="center" align-v="start">
            <!-- Card Inline Template -->
            <card
                  inline-template
                  v-for="card in cards"
                  v-bind="{card: card}"
                  :key="card.id"
            >
                <b-card
                        v-bind:title=card.title
                        img-src="https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=25"
                        img-alt="Image"
                        img-top
                        style="max-width: 370px; margin: 5px"
                        class="no-select"
                >
                    <b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-' + card.id">Button</b-button>
                    <b-collapse v-bind:id="'collapse-' + card.id" class="mt-2">
                        <v-calendar
                                is-expanded
                                :min-date='new Date()'
                        >
                        </v-calendar>
                    </b-collapse>
                </b-card>
            </card>
        </b-row>

    </b-container>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Vue.component('card', {
    props: {
        card: {
            required: true,
            default: {id: 0, title: 'Default.'}
        }
    }
});

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        cards: []
    }
})

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.app.cards.push({id: 0, title: '1'})
    }, 1000);
});
```